# What does 5 x 10 mean in Dell Support Context?

Tags: dell

3Yr Basic Hardware Warranty Repair: 5x10 HW-Only, 5x10 NBD Onsite

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Support during business hours only. 5 days a week, 10 hours a day. 7x24 is 7 days a week, any time of day.

Answer (score 4):

3 years of hardware only warranty repair. 5 days a week, 10 hours a day in your time zone, onsite by the next business day.